# Artifactory aql search error: "Props Authentication Token not found" 403

Tags: python, gitlab-ci, artifactory

I have a pipeline running in GitLab. I want it to do an aql search for Artifactory to collect information about my images.

For this I send a POST request to

```
https://{url}/artifactory/api/search/aql
```

with my aql request in the body and this header:

```
headers = {'X-JFrog-Art-Api': token,
           'content-type': "text/plain"}
```

When I run my function in IntelliJ it works without problems, but as soon as I do it with an Api key from a service account with all permissions I get this 403 error:

```
b'{\n "errors" : [ {\n "status" : 403,\n "message" : "Props Authentication Token not found"} ]\n}'
```

Comment: quick question, how you generated this token? Also, is this an access token or an API Key?